# How can I display numbers with higher precision in a MATLAB data cursor?

Tags: matlab, plot, precision, datatip

I have a problem with precision loss. I imported a set of values from a CSV file into MATLAB 7 using the following code:

```
function importfile(fileToRead1)
%#IMPORTFILE(FILETOREAD1)
%#  Imports data from the specified file
%#  FILETOREAD1:  file to read

DELIMITER = ',';
HEADERLINES = 0;

%# Import the file
rawData1 = importdata(fileToRead1, DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);

%# For some simple files (such as a CSV or JPEG files), IMPORTDATA might
%# return a simple array.  If so, generate a structure so that the output
%# matches that from the Import Wizard.
[~,name] = fileparts(fileToRead1);
newData1.(genvarname(name)) = rawData1;

%# Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
```

This very basic script just takes the specified file:

```
> 14,-0.15893555 
> 15,-0.24221802
> 16,0.18478394
```

And converts the second column to:

```
14  -0,158935550000000
15  -0,242218020000000
16  0,184783940000000
```

However, if I select a point with the Data Cursor it only displays 3 or 4 digits of precision:

[image: imprecise labels]

Is there a way to program a higher precision to get more exact data points?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your *data* isn't losing precision, the Data Cursor display just isn't *showing* the full precision so that the text boxes are a more reasonable size. However, if you want to increase the precision of the display in the text datatip, [you can customize it](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html).

If you right click on a Data Cursor text box, you should see a menu like this:

[image]

If you then select the **Edit Text Update Function...** option, it will open a default m-file containing the following:

```
function output_txt = myfunction(obj, event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ', num2str(pos(1), 4)], ...
              ['Y: ', num2str(pos(2), 4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ', num2str(pos(3), 4)];
end
```

Notice that the text for the X and Y coordinate data is formatted using [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), with the second argument being a `4`. This converts the coordinate value to a string representation with 4 digits of precision. If you want more digits displayed, simply increase this number, then save the newly-created m-file on your [path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html).

Now your datatip text should display more precision for your numbers. If you want to accomplish all of the above *programmatically*, you would first create your text update function, save it to a file (like `'updateFcn.m'`), then turn on Data Cursors using the function [`datacursormode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) and set them to use your user-defined text update function. Here's an example:

```
plot(1:10, rand(1, 10));  % Plot some sample data
dcmObj = datacursormode;  % Turn on data cursors and return the
                          %   data cursor mode object
set(dcmObj, 'UpdateFcn', @updateFcn);  % Set the data cursor mode object update
                                       %   function so it uses updateFcn.m
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You save me a lot of typing.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  I have always done the "export cursor to workspace" to get the needed precision.  This is a very useful trick.

Comment: This is a good answer, but am I the only one that thinks it's incredible (in a bad way) that this IS the answer?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make a permanent change - Warning: This is a slight hack to MATLAB - open:

C:\Program Files\Matlab\R2007b\toolbox\matlab\graphics\@graphics\@datacursor\default_getDatatipText.m

or a similar file depending on your version and change DEFAULT_DIGITS.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote me on this, but:

1) You haven't lost precision, MATLAB stores the full value, it is only the display that has been pared down.

2) In my version of MATLAB (R2009a) I can modify the way long numbers are shown in the command menu by going to

File>Preferences>Variable Editor

where a dropdown menu lets me pick between short, long, short e, long e, short g, long g, short eng, long eng, bank, + and rat.

I have no idea whether that affects what the Data Cursor shows, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your script:

```
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
set(dcm_obj,'Updatefcn',@myfunction_datacursor);
```

You need to create and save `myfunction_datacursor` file with the following in your path (get path by calling `path` in MATLAB prompt)

```
function output_txt = myfunction_datacursor(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),8)],...
        ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
        output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),8)];
end
```